# sketching a graph with sine

Tags: calculus

Sketch $y = 3 \sin(x - {\pi\over 4})$ for $0 \lt x \lt 2\pi$ showing intercepts and turning points.

I know how to sketch graphs for polynomials, I would:

1. Find the x intercepts when $y = 0$
2. Find y intercepts when $x = 0$
3. Find the stationary points by differentiating $f(x)$
4. Investigate the nature of these points between the range specified above.

I don't know know how to do any of these points when a sine value is involved.

I think ${{dy\over dx} = 3 \cos(x - {\pi\over4})}$

Comment: Do you know the basic graph of $\sin x$?

Comment: Find points where $y(x) = 0$ and points where $y(x) = \pm 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic form for the sine graph is as follows:

$$f(x)= a\sin b(x-c)+d$$

$a$ is the amplitude of the graph. It is both how far above and how far below the center of the graph the extrema are.

$b$ is a period shift. You have none.

$c$ is a horizontal phase shift. Your graph is being shifted $\pi /4$ units to the right.

$d$ is a vertical phase shift. You have none.

Using your knowledge of $\sin(x)$ and these transformations, can you sketch the graph?

Answer (score 1):

> Sketch $y = 3 \sin(x - {\pi\over 4})$ for $0 \lt x \lt 2\pi$

**Hints:**

1. Find the $x$ intercepts when $y = 0$:

Note that $\sin \theta =0$ for $\theta =\dots,-2\pi,-\pi,0,\pi,2\pi,\dots$

So you should check when $x - {\pi\over 4}=\dots,-2\pi,-\pi,0,\pi,2\pi,\dots$

don't forget that $0 \lt x \lt 2\pi$

---

2. Find y intercepts when x = 0

You have

$\sin(0-\frac{\pi}{4})=\text{ you can check the answer in calculator}$

---

3. Find the stationary points by differentiating $f(x)$

Note that $\left(\beta \sin(g(x))\right)'=\beta\cos(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$

---

4. Investigate the nature of these points between the range specified above.

Use a table and check when $f'(x)>0$ and when $f'(x)<0$

Also I recommend to know by heart the graph of $\sin x:$

[image]